# Input fields inside div of the same form cannot be processed

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, html

I have a form in my ASPX page which is processed by the code behind c#.
It was working fine, until I needed to `hide` or `show` certain inputs based on user needs.
This part also works well, but when I put in the divs, my c# cannot get the form values anymore.
Here's a simulation of my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <table width="100%" frame=box>
      <tr>
         <td>
           <div id='firstText' runat="server">
             <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                        <input name="INPUT1" id="idInput1" runat="server" type="radio" value="someVal" checked />
                  </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id='secondText' runat="server">
             <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                        <input name="INPUT2" id="idInput2" runat="server" type="radio" value="someVal2" checked />
                  </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
string selectedOption = Request.Form["INPUT2"];
```

With the above case, what I get in `selectionOption` is always `null`. 
But when I remove the divs from the code, everything is fine.

Any suggestion is appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a submit button, selectedOption value comes correctly. Sample code is below.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="NestedIdTest.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <table width="100%" frame=box>
      <tr>
         <td>
           <div id='firstText' runat="server">
             <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                        <input name="INPUT1" id="idInput1" runat="server" type="radio" value="someVal" checked />
                  </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id='secondText' runat="server">
             <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                        <input name="INPUT2" id="idInput2" runat="server" type="radio" value="someVal2" checked />
                  </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs (Code behind)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NestedIdTest
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedOption = Request.Form["INPUT2"];
        }
    }
}
```

Please note added line to Default.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

I already had a submit button, forgot to mention it in the simulated code.
I found the problem already. Just going to elaborate it in case if some one faced this.

On the page load of the code behind I was hiding one of the divs by default

```
secondText.visible = false;
```

That's why I couldn't read values of its inputs. 
In fact, I expected a component's value to be accessible even if it is not visible. I am not disabling it, just changing the visible attribute.

Anyway, learned something new! 
I created a hidden div in the visible one to hold the value of what I wanted in the hidden one. So even if the div is hidden I can get the value I want from the shown one.

Regards.